# PHP Text concatenation Issue

Tags: php, text

Actual Syntax

```
{"country": "UK","value": 19},
```

How to get this output in PHP using variable values against UK and 19 in above code?

LIKE

```
{"country": "$Variable val",   "value": $Variable val 2 },
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, please clarify

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array and use json_encode like this:

```
 $arr = array();
 $arr['country'] = $yourvar1;
 $arr['value'] = $yourvar2;


 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode` and `compact` is a nice way to create the array:

```
$country = 'UK';
$value = 19;
echo json_encode(compact('country', 'value'));
```

You could also just pass an array:

```
$array = array('country' => 'UK', 'value' => 19);
echo json_encode($array);
```

`json_encode`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

`compact`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score -1):

$var1 = 'UK';
$var2 = 19;

echo '{"country": "'.$var1.'",   "value":'.$var2.' }';

although jsonifying is better idea